# Locking the stage in the opportunity. VR

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

**A.** I am trying to prevent the team from changing the opportunity stage from "Accepted Oppty" to any of the followings: Cold, Early, Late.
I haven't been able to get this one to work.

**B.** I am also trying to prevent the team from changing the opportunity stage to 
Accepted Oppty" from any of the following: Cold, Early, Late.
I was able to get this one to work. Here is the code:

```
AND( 
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Accepted Oppty"),false, 
OR( 
ISCHANGED(Amount), 
ISCHANGED(CloseDate), 
ISCHANGED(StageName)))
```

Is there a way to combine A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula. Its satisfy both condition.

```
AND( 
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
ISCHANGED(StageName),
OR(AND(
ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Accepted Oppty"), 
OR(ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Cold"),ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Early"),ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Late"))),
AND(
OR(ISPICKVAL(  PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Cold"),ISPICKVAL(  PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Early"),ISPICKVAL(  PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Late")), ISPICKVAL( StageName, "Accepted Oppty")
)
))
```